# Remapping the up/down arrow keys in TexStudio so that I can move up and down within the auto-completion suggestion box

Tags: macros, texstudio, auto-completion, keyboard, shortcut

I created shortcuts in TexStudio for the arrow keys (Ctrl+J, Ctrl+L, Ctrl+I, Ctrl+K for Left, Right, Up, Down) so that I can keep my fingers on the homerow keys, rather than moving them to the bottom-right of the keyboard everytime I want to move my cursor.

The shortcuts work fine in the editor, however, when the auto-completion suggestion box pops up I can't use the shortcuts to go up and down the selections.  I need to use the regular arrow keys again.

Is there a way to remap the up and down arrow keys so that they work in the editor AND within the auto-completion suggestion box?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. I think it is better to ask that for developers [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio). But, if you type few letters more, the completion should accurate and then simply press `return`.

Comment: Ok, I will post my question there.  Thank you for the suggestion.